# How to run Python script with a custom button

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to run the Python script when I press the button. This code only opens the script when I click the button.

```
import sys
import os
import tkinter
top=tkinter.Tk()
def helloCallBack():
    os.system('img.py')
B=tkinter.Button(top,text="Run",command= helloCallBack)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

**How to make it run the img.py**

Comment: `os.system('python img.py')`

Comment: How about defining what in `img.py` as a function so you can import and use it at `command=` ?

Comment: Just so You know, running the other script like this may freeze the current script since `os.system` is blocking the `mainloop()` by executing the other script, You could for example start a new thread with `os.system` to avoid this

Comment: Set execution bit  `chmod +x img.py`  then include a hashbang header on script  `#! /usr/bin/python3` -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 0):

```
button=Button(top, text="Run",command=helloCallBack)
```

This will run the function that you define fine.
If you want a python script to appear

```
def helloCallBack():
    os.system('python img.py')
```